# How to remove custom javascript reference from Drupal 7 subtheme

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap-3, drupal-7

Following the guide on managing javascript in Drupal 7 I added a "myjs.js" file in my sites/all/themes/mytheme/js folder, and included a line in the mytheme.info file (scripts[] = js/myjs.js).  When I view page source on my site I can see the file is loaded.

Following a number of issues, I tried to back out of this.  I removed the scripts[] line in the mytheme.info file, and deleted the js file from the js folder.  So, theoretically, my drupal 7 site should have no knowledge of my custom js file, right?

Well, after numerous clearing of caches, hard reload of browser, even stop/restart my xampp server, whenever I view source on my site I see that file is still referenced as being loaded.

Must be a database thing?  Where else would Drupal store and therefore persist my reference?

I also tried adding a new js file in the .info file (e.g., "js/newjs.js") and after clearing cache I never see the new file.  Only the old, original file is there.

I'm using a bootstrap subtheme, and have checked both bootstrap.info and of course mytheme.info and there is NO reference to the myjs.js file anywhere.

This is exasperating.  Any thoughts where I might look (database record, e.g.,).

THanks.

Comment: Are you also getting the file in a different browser? (Also, issues like this are commonly solved by discovering you haven't actually uploaded recent changes)

Comment: Also is good on page '/admin/config/development/performance' to uncheck  'Aggregate and compress CSS files' and ' Aggregate JavaScript files' when develop site.

Comment: I've tried different browser (same file reference persists).  Also tried disabling/re-enabling the main bootstrap theme (can't disable a subtheme apparently).  Checked and unchecked the aggregate/etc., and also deleted cache and history from browser.  What I'm thinking now is that the .info file is not being reloaded.  For example, if I put in a different scripts[] = "newjs".js reference, the new file is never shown in page source.  Only the old file is shown.  And, when I click on the link in the source the js code that is displayed is "old".....no updates are loaded. Seems a .info issue?

Comment: Just to clarify, when I click "show page source" I see this reference to my js file:  <script src="http://127.0.0.1/mysite/sites/all/themes/mybootstrapsubtheme/js/mythemejs.js?owkfps"></script>  - then when I click on that link, I see old js code from long ago. At some point, .info loaded this js file, and no matter what I do I cannot update or change it (the old js file and its code always shows), nor can I put a different file in the .info file and load it instead.  Hope this makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

Found the problem.  I'm using AMPP as localhost server.  When I first set this up I installed the D7 on my D: drive...or so I thought.  I'm not sure exactly how AMPP works but I found there is another installation on my C drive in the Systems folder.  Therefore, I have two installs, and thought I was working on the D drive version all this time.  Oddly, both of them are "almost" in synch....so at some point recently the D drive version was running, but now it's the C. I never did a restore so have no idea whether the C drive is/was a "clone" of the D drive install.  Whatever.  Feel so stooopid.  I guess the key learning is when everything should be working but isn't, and if odd things are happening, look for the simple-stoopid things you might have done.  Chris G was almost on point...I had uploaded the js and .info files, but to the D drive!